# Cannot run bash script from task scheduler with Windows 1607

Tags: command-line, bash, scheduled-tasks, windows-10-v1607, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I need to make a scheduled task to run a bash script on Windows 10 new release.
The script works fine from bash, works fine from cmd or PowerShell, but if I run it from Task Scheduler it comes up blank.
I've tried with task parameters like "start a program " with arguments "bash ", and with bat file to start the script. No luck.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In the arguments, use *nix path such as the one below:

> /mnt/c/Test/myscript.sh

.. where Windows equivalent path is `C:\Test\myscript.sh`